# Trying to make a dice roller thats able to roll a die with a specific number of sides a specific number of times via a single input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, dice, random

So far, i am using .charAt() to discern the first and 3rd characters in say "1d6", meaning roll a six sided die once. To do this i have made a for loop to use the random class with a range of 1 and the die type (in this case 6), and the loop is supposed to execute it a number of times determined by the input (in this case, 1). Problem is the values im getting are rather random.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class DiceRoller3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creates a new scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Creates a new Random object
    Random random = new Random();

    //fluff text
    //System.out.println("What would you like to roll?");

    //Sets dieInput equal to the input the scanner reads.
    String dieInput = input.next();

    //sets noOfDice equal the the first character of the dieInput String
    int noOfDice = dieInput.charAt(0);

    //sets dieType equal to the 3rd character of the dieInput String
    int dieType = dieInput.charAt(2);

    //test to show the value of noOfDice and dieType
    System.out.println(dieInput);
    System.out.println(noOfDice);
    System.out.println(dieType);


    //Loop to roll the die type determined by the input, a number of times 
    that is also determined by the input
    for(int x = 1; x <= noOfDice; x++)
    {
        int roll = random.nextInt(dieType) + 1;

        System.out.println(roll);
    }

}
```

}

When i run this, the the program tells me that the value of noOfDice and dieType are equal to 49 or 50 or some other large number which i'm not understanding why that is the case. the value of dieInput is correct, but when the two characters are read from dieInput they become incorrect. any thoughts on why that could be? as well as any other issues in my code.

Disclaimer: Im rather new to coding, and im trying to do this with what i know (scanner and random for example) i imagine there are more efficient ways to do what i wanna do, but im trying to do it with the tools that i have.

Comment: When you call dieInput.charAt(n), you'll need to convert it to an int before storing it in noOfDive or dieType. Try calling Character.getNumericValue(c) and storing that.

Comment: Aside: since you're using `charAt(2)` you'll only get 1 digit. What happens for `2d12`? What happens for `10d4`? You could instead _split_ the input string `String[] values = dieInput.split("d")` which will give you the count in `values[0]` and the sides in `values[1]`, even for something like `25d100` — you _still_ have to convert to Integers, like Nicholas K says (but probably with `Integer.parseInt(values[0])` since it's a String, not a Character.

Comment: @Mobeus : Any answer that satisfies your question?

Answer (score 3):

Two issues with your code :

1. Change

   ```
   // this gets the ASCII value which is why you are getting weird numbers 
   // ASCII value of 1 is 49
   int noOfDice = dieInput.charAt(0);
   ```

   to

   ```
   // this gets numeric value of the character
   int noOfDice = Character.getNumericValue(dieInput.charAt(0));
   int dieType = Character.getNumericValue(dieInput.charAt(2));
   ```
2. Use this to generate random numbers between 1 and `dietype` :

   ```
   int minVal = 1;
   int roll = (minVal + random.nextInt(dieType - minVal + 1);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

With some OOP thinking, I'd write the `Dice` class. For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    private int sides;

    private Dice(){
        //no Dice constructor without the sides parameter
    }

    public Dice(int sides){
        if (sides <= 0){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        else {
            this.sides = sides;
        }
    }

    public int getSides(){
        return this.sides;
    }

    private int rollMyDice(){
        return  1 + RANDOM.nextInt(this.sides);
    }

    public List<Integer> rollMyDiceManyTimes(int howManyRolling){
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < howManyRolling; i++){
            result.add(rollMyDice());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then, you can test it, (and/or rewrite the code to satisfied your goals):

```
public class Answer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //test
        Dice dice = new Dice(9);
        System.out.println("I'm rolling the dice with "
                + dice.getSides()
                + " sides "
                + " ELEVEN TIMES "
                + dice.rollMyDiceManyTimes(11));

    }
}
```

Of course, this is just a template I tried to provide to you...

Some output will be:

```
I'm rolling the dice with 9 sides  ELEVEN TIMES [9, 4, 5, 2, 8, 7, 3, 8, 2, 1, 4]
```

Comment: +1 this is essentially what I did at some point in the past. My usage was slightly different... `Dice d6 = new Dice(6); int total = d6.roll(3);` & if you wanted the individual die rolls: `Integer[] rolls = d6.lastRoll();`

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the numbers from your string as integers, not chars.  Here is one of many ways

```
String[] numbers = dieInput.split("d"); // "1d6" split into "1" and "6"
int noOfDie = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
int dieType = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
```

This will avoid the problem you're running into where you're getting the ascii value (which is also an int) from the `char` value you're getting back from the `string.charAt()` method.

Edit:

The `numbers` array in my snippet represents the result of the split input.  Based on the expected input of two numbers separated by a `d` such as `1d6` or `3d10`, the result would be an array with 2 items in it, the number before the `d` and the number after it.  If, for example, you called the split method and the input string had multiple `d` characters, you'd get a bigger array.  For example, `1d6d7` would result in an array with 3 items in it, `"1"`, `"6"` and `"7"`.  Even though the contents are of type string, I contextually expect them their values to be numbers.  Which is why in the following lines `Integer.parseInt()` is used to convert the value from a String to an int.  This only works when the value of the string is a valid int.

Comment: For some reason    "String[] numbers = input.split("d");" isnt working, its telling me its not a part of the scanner class, any idea why?

Comment: I'm sorry, where I said `input` I meant `dieInput`.  Fixed.

Comment: what does the variable "numbers" represent in your code?

Comment: nvm i figured it out, sorry

Comment: I elaborated anyways, hopefully that clarifies more